# Android Recycler view inside Viewpager and Recyclerview and Common Pattern

Tags: android

Hi I have two question about scrolling behavior of android layout

Currently I have Following structure

```
CoordinatorLayout 
  - AppbarLayout
     - Toolbar
     - TabLayout
  - ViewPager
```

For Toolbar, app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" is set.

And inside ViewPager, There is RecyclerView1. and for it's item,

```
FrameLayout 
  - CardView
     - Toolbar
     - RecyclerView2
```

**Q1.**
When I scroll recyclerView2, Scrolling event doesn't seem to propagate to upper layers.

When I scroll recyclerView1's own item, Toolbar collapses and content inside ViewPager scrolls well.

But when I scroll recyclerView2's own item, toolbar doesn't collapses but content inside ViewPager scrolls.

why these thing happen? do i have to set recyclerView2's scroll 'disabled'?

how can i make my UI to have constant behavior? I want toolbar to collapse even if i scroll with RecyclerView2.

I'm using support library 24 and autoMesurement enabled for recyclerview.

**Q2.**
To tell the fact i am practicing to make live-score sports application.
So it goes like

```
Premier League(CardView as Item of RecyclerView)
  Game1(RecyclerView)
  Game2

Champions League(CardView as Item of RecyclerView)
  Game1(RecyclerView)
  Game2
```

I am kind of new to android so I wonder this kind of RecyclerView inside RecyclerView pattern is so common.

I implemented this way because i heard it's recommended to use recyclerView instead of ListView.

So I'm curios what other developers do when implementing (header-list)-list style in android.

Comment: try recyclerView1.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: calling that method to recyclerView1 didn't work as expected but calling it with recyclerView2 Worked